# cabal: Encountered missing dependencies: z3 >=4.1.0

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

I tried to install [wiretap-tools](https://github.com/ucla-pls/wiretap-tools) from its repository. When I run `cabal configure` from inside the folder, I get :

```
cabal: Encountered missing dependencies:
z3 >=4.1.0
```

I have already installed z3 using `sudo apt-get install z3`. I added `/usr/bin` to path variable, where z3 seems to be installed. When I run `z3 -version`, I get `Z3 version 4.8.0 - 64 bit`. Still the configure command gives the error.

Answer (score 5):

The missing dependency is not the `z3` program which you got from `apt-get` but the `z3` haskell library. You can install it like any other cabal library. Typically you set up a sandbox and then run `cabal install --only-dependencies` or using the more modern new-build run `cabal new-build` and it manages all that for you.